# How to replace NaN and NaT with None - pandas 0.24.1

Tags: python, pandas

I need to replace all `NaN` and `NaT` in a `pandas.Series` with a `None`.

I tried this:

```
def replaceMissing(ser):
    return ser.where(pd.notna(ser), None)
```

But it does not work:

```
import pandas as pd

NaN = float('nan')
NaT = pd.NaT

floats1 = pd.Series((NaN, NaN, 2.71828, -2.71828))
floats2 = pd.Series((2.71828, -2.71828, 2.71828, -2.71828))
dates = pd.Series((NaT, NaT, pd.Timestamp("2019-07-09"), pd.Timestamp("2020-07-09")))


def replaceMissing(ser):
    return ser.where(pd.notna(ser), None)


print(pd.__version__)
print(80*"-")
print(replaceMissing(dates))
print(80*"-")
print(replaceMissing(floats1))
print(80*"-")
print(replaceMissing(floats2))
```

As you can see the `NaT` was not replaced:

```
0.24.1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
0          NaT
1          NaT
2   2019-07-09
3   2020-07-09
dtype: datetime64[ns]
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
0       None
1       None
2    2.71828
3   -2.71828
dtype: object
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
0    2.71828
1   -2.71828
2    2.71828
3   -2.71828
dtype: float64
```

Then I tried this extra step:

```
def replaceMissing(ser):
    ser = ser.where(pd.notna(ser), None)
    return ser.replace({pd.NaT: None})
```

But it still does not work. It brings back the `NaN`s for some reason:

```
0.24.1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
0                   None
1                   None
2    2019-07-09 00:00:00
3    2020-07-09 00:00:00
dtype: object
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
0        NaN
1        NaN
2    2.71828
3   -2.71828
dtype: float64
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
0    2.71828
1   -2.71828
2    2.71828
3   -2.71828
dtype: float64
```

I also tried converting the series into `object`:

```
def replaceMissing(ser):
    return ser.astype("object").where(pd.notna(ser), None)
```

But now the last series is also `object` even though it has no missing values:

```
0.24.1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
0                   None
1                   None
2    2019-07-09 00:00:00
3    2020-07-09 00:00:00
dtype: object
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
0       None
1       None
2    2.71828
3   -2.71828
dtype: object
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
0    2.71828
1   -2.71828
2    2.71828
3   -2.71828
dtype: object
```

I would like it to remain `float64`. So I add `infer_objects`:

```
def replaceMissing(ser):
    return ser.astype("object").where(pd.notna(ser), None).infer_objects()
```

But it brings back the `NaN`s again:

```
0.24.1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
0                   None
1                   None
2    2019-07-09 00:00:00
3    2020-07-09 00:00:00
dtype: object
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
0        NaN
1        NaN
2    2.71828
3   -2.71828
dtype: float64
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
0    2.71828
1   -2.71828
2    2.71828
3   -2.71828
dtype: float64
```

I feel like there's got to be an easy way to do this. Does anyone know?

Comment: Sorry but this won't work, `None` is a python object dtype so you have to convert the dtype of the column to `object` in order to do this, what are you trying to achieve by doing this is the question?

Comment: @EdChum Why not? If a series only has non-missing floats it can remain a `float64` series.

Comment: `None` is not the same as `NaN` so it cannot be represented by a `float` dtype, so once you insert `None` it immediately changes the dtype to `object`. The question remains what are you trying to achieve here with `None` that `NaN` doesn't do?

Comment: @EdChum I am trying to achieve the behavior where if a series of `float64` values has no `NaN`s then it should remain a series of `float64` instead of turning into a series of `object`.

Comment: No, I'm asking why are you trying to replace `NaN`, `NaT` with `None` in the first place?

Comment: I need to do this in order to to pass the series to some code that cannot handle NaN and NaT, but can handle None.

Comment: @jezrael fair enough but it's impossible to maintain the dtype as `float` once you add `None` to the `Series` so if you need this, do it but understand the the `dtype` has to change to `object` there is no way around this

Comment: @EdChum - yes, if need dtype floats with None, it is impossible, like dtype datetime64 with None. Then close what OP need is my answer.

Answer (score 2):

For me working change order of your second solution, tested in `0.24.2`, but `dtype`s is changed to object, because mixed types - `None`s with `float`s or `timestamp`s:

```
def replaceMissing(ser):
    return ser.replace({pd.NaT: None}).where(pd.notna(ser), None)

print(pd.__version__)
print(80*"-")
print(replaceMissing(dates))
print(80*"-")
print(replaceMissing(dates).apply(type))
print(80*"-")
print(replaceMissing(floats1))
print(80*"-")
print(replaceMissing(floats1).apply(type))
print(80*"-")
print(replaceMissing(floats2))
```

---

```
0.24.2
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
0                   None
1                   None
2    2019-07-09 00:00:00
3    2020-07-09 00:00:00
dtype: object
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
0                                   <class 'NoneType'>
1                                   <class 'NoneType'>
2    <class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timesta...
3    <class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timesta...
dtype: object
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
0       None
1       None
2    2.71828
3   -2.71828
dtype: object
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
0    <class 'NoneType'>
1    <class 'NoneType'>
2       <class 'float'>
3       <class 'float'>
dtype: object
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
0    2.71828
1   -2.71828
2    2.71828
3   -2.71828
dtype: float64
```

Comment: This works for me too, but I don't understand why if you switch the order it doesn't.

Comment: @spiderface - I think because pandas working best with same dtypes - all values in column are floats or datetimes (so `NaN` or `NaT`), this is a bit hack ;)

Comment: I guess the less hacky way is to use a condition:
`def replaceMissing(ser):
 if ser.isna().any():
  return ser.astype("object").where(pd.notna(ser), None)
 else:
  return ser`

Comment: @spiderface - yes, but `if-else` not necessary - `def replaceMissing(ser):
    return ser.astype("object").where(pd.notna(ser), None)`

Comment: But I want to keep the dtype whenever possible.

Comment: @spiderface - ya, then `if-else` is necessary ;)